# Java Guice: If you inject the same dependency multiple times, is the same instance of that dependency injected?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs, guice

I have a java jersey 2.x project, using Guice as my dependency injection framework. I have this service

```
public class AccountService {

private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Inject
public AccountService(InMemoryAccountRepositoryImpl inMemoryAccountRepositoryImpl) {
    this.accountRepository = inMemoryAccountRepositoryImpl;
}
```

Let's say that I create another service class that also injects `InMemoryAccountRepositoryImpl`, will the same instance be injected? It's important for me to know, because this instance has an internal state that needs to be consistent.

Comment: As an aside, you should [program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2587435), meaning inject interface types, not concrete types. Use `bind(InterfaceType.class).to(ConcreteType.class)` in your Guice configuration.

Comment: Oh I see, it's a lot cleaner. If I need to change the implementation of the class, instead of changing it in every constructor it's injected in, I change it in the Guice config once. Pretty neat, thx @PaulSamsotha !

Comment: Yeah, and (unit) testing is a lot easier. You can just mock out dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Guice returns a new instance each time it supplies a value. This behaviour is configurable via scopes. Scopes allow you to reuse instances: for the lifetime of an application (@Singleton), a session (@SessionScoped), or a request (@RequestScoped). Guice includes a servlet extension that defines scopes for web apps. Custom scopes can be written for other types of applications.

for more info see the [documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes)

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the Singleton annotation and it worked!